# initializing a character array with exact length in C?

Tags: c

```
char ch[2];
ch[0] = 'h';
ch[1] = '\0';
```

or can i just do

```
char ch[1];
ch[0] = 'h';
```

in which '\0' would already be implied?

The reason why i'm doing it this way is because my program has a loop in it in which i would constantly be changing this character and concatenating it to a longer string.

Comment: The `\o` stands for end of string, so whenever you `printf("%s", ch);` the function search for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning just `ch[0]` will not assign zero to the `ch[1]`. You can initialize both characters in the array with a string literal in a single line, like this:

```
char ch[2] = "h";
```

This will put `'h'` into `ch[0]`, and a terminating zero into `ch[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit terminating null characters if you like, but you won't be able to use functions that expect a terminating null character like `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option if you plan to be using this single-character string over and over is to just initialise the null once.  Then you only ever have to change the first character:

```
char ch[2] = {0};
ch[0] = 'h';
```

In your second case, you don't need to declare an array:

```
char ch = 'h';
```

But you can't use that as a string.  There is no implied null character in your single-character 'array'.

Why can't you just append characters to your string instead of strings?  You don't need `strcat`, if that's what this is about...  You just keep appending single characters until you are done and then you append a null.

```
char somestring[100];
char pos = 0;
while( ... ) {
    somestring[pos] = 'x';  /* or whatever */
    pos = pos + 1;
} 
somestring[pos] = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

`ch` is an char array and not a string.

The compiler can recognize it as a string only if you add the `'\0'`; however, it cannot recognize it as an array of char.

So, you must add the `'\0'`, you can do like this:

```
int ind=0;
while(...)
{
    ch[ind++]='h';
}
ch[ind]='\0';
```

Comment: C does not have strings, only char arrays that can be treated as strings. The **compiler** does not recognize char arrays as strings no matter what they contain ... perhaps you mean "the implementation" or "the C library". And your loop doesn't apply to the OP's question, which is about a single char or a string of length 1.